# Profile PHP code on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am a newbie when it comes to using PHP on G.A.E.

Some of my code runs extremely slowly. Is there any way I can profile my code to help me find the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code runs slowly using [development app server locally then just attach XDebug](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/devserver#PHP_Local_debugging_with_XDebug) and related friends like you normally would (search for php profiling and such if you have not done so before).

If it only occurs in production then perhaps you can point us to the app so we can take a look.